# Issue with replacing a server 2016 (Datacenter edition) Storage pool drive

Tags: windows-server-2016

I have a storage pool that I originally configured on win server 2012r2, but when that server boot drive failed like a year ago I replaced it and installed server 2016. The storage pool is a thin’ly provisioned 20TB virtual disk with pairty spread across six 5TB external usb drives (all arranged on a nice looking magazine rack with a gigabyte brix driving the show, cable managed and setup to be a living room staple).

This is what I like to call a production lab, as I try to do things in a production like manner but it is still a lab for my learning benefit and to test things out. However it also acts as a file server and I use it a lot for that.

Anyways the drives are like 6 years old and one of them started making some very ominous sounds (but still reported working fine. So I ordered it’s replacement and it arrived today a upgrade from 5tb to 8tb on the drive. I shut the computer down unplugged the old drive used its connections to plug in the new drive and started futzing with storage pools having never done this before.

Now the 8TB drive is listed as part of the pool, but the 5tb drive that is physically unplugged cannot be removed from the pool nor reset. It complains that I have to replace the drive (but i did), I hit repair virtual drive several times but it completes much to quick to be doing anything. The old 5tb drive are actually using about 3.??TB of their space the new 8TB drive is using about 2 gigs. the get-storagejob command returns literally nothing but a new prompt.

I cannot remove either the 8tb or the 5tb drive from the pool because it wants a replacement drive when the 8tb drive was supposed to be //the replacement//.

Helps please

**I got server 2012r2 as a college student through dreamspark now I am an employee at a college that gets a free class per-semester so I got 2016 also as a student through Azure Education (Dreamspark Rebranded). I don't use this for anything that makes money just personal projects/ learning, and a file server for my other computers which I do actively use. Hope this prevents people from getting caught up on how I have server datacenter

Comment: Sounds like, possibly, you need to clear all metadata (File System Utility): https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-resource  There is also this page: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storagereplica/clear-srmetadata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is more or less resolved now, recording here for the benefit of the next noob like myself to come across something like this.

After my attempts to do this on my own I found This article 
( https://www.servethehome.com/windows-server-2016-storage-spaces-how-to-replace-failed-hard-drive/ ) 
Which would have been great starting at ground zero but my attempts had left me in a hole I had to get out of first before that article would apply...

Problem was mainly I could not find evidence that anything was happening so I did things to try and make things happen which likely shot myself in the foot.

My initial attempt started by unplugging the 'to be decommissioned' drive and plugging in it's replacement. The moment I did that there was a yellow triangle next to the storagepool saying 'Degraded' (expected). I then tried for a while to figure out how to add the new drive to the pool, eventually cleaning it with diskpart and then being able to refresh the drive screen and then add it. I then went to remove the old drive and it looked like it worked and gave me a message about leaving alone until 'in-service status' was gone.... Except I did not see the in-service status literally anywhere (it was hidden in that yellow triangle that had said degraded, it was also under health on the properties page for the pool... now I know).

Also The drive appeared to still be there, so I tried a few more times to remove it even rebooted the server and tried again and I had got myself in a chicken-egg problem where the replacement drive couldn't be removed without it's own replacement nor could the drive it was intended to replace be removed for the same reason.

Due to the parity of the pool my data (7.48TB used of the 20TB available, on 30TB worth of disks but you know um parity..) was still available though from the way this was going I was getting more and more paranoid of losing that data. I had a hand-me-down NAS (px12-400r IOMega/EMC) that I had earmarked for a different project and whilst it didn't have 20TB it did have more then the 7.48 so I backed my data up to it which took about 48hrs.

Anyways That backup finished today, and I should mentioned I plugged the original drive back in for this backup (it still worked as far as any tool would say, it is just making end of life sounds (clicking, and a sound that is probably disk flutter but sounds kinda like a electrical arc).

After 48 or so hours of a NAS initiated file copy and otherwise leaving it alone, I tried refreshing the storage pool drives and removing the 8TB drive, not expecting for a second that it would work, as it had failed on many previous tries.... BUT IT DID WORK...

My assumption is in my meddling either tasks were pending or stalled out preventing me from doing anything, or the system had not realized that this pool drive had no data on it as it had just been added. Regardless after 48 hours I was able to remove the new drive from the pool (and reset it to get rid of the error flag). This left me back at where I started, no better but at least no worse either.

I then followed the guide in that link at the start of this post 'to the letter' and now the old drive whilst still plugged in is removed from the pool (took a few hours to go from 'retired' status to no longer in the pool but an available primordial drive) and the new drive is being rebuilt presently, with 2.4TB used so far (all the other drives are a bit over 3TB each in used space). I should mention the old drive is plugged in where it always was and the new drive is plugged in via spare usb plug and the connections that came with it in the box, when the rebuild is done the old drive will go and the new drive will assume it's physical spot and connections.

Technically it's not done yet but it appears to be at a place that left well enough alone will be done in a few hours.